# No puedo traer informacion de mysql en formulario con flask

Tags: mysql, flask

Hola a todos mi pregunta es porque no puedo traer información de la base de datos mysql ..tengo un formulario en html estoy utilizando flask y coloco un valor en el input y al presionar "enter"
 necesito que rellene los demas controles con los datos relacionados

este es el codigo en html

```
 <div class="body">
                        <form  method="post" action="/consultamovil">
                            <div class="row clearfix">

                                 <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-horizontal">
                                                <label class="control-label">Patente</label>
                                                <input  type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese Patente del móvil" name = "patente">
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!--/span-->
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-horizontal">
                                                <label class="control-label">Area</label>
                                                <input  type="text"  class="form-control form-control-danger" placeholder="Area Responsable" name= "area" >
                                                </small> </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!--/span-->

                                         <!--/span-->
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-horizontal">
                                                <label class="control-label">Interno</label>
                                                <input  type="text"  class="form-control form-control-danger" placeholder="Interno" name="interno" >
                                                </small> </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!--/span-->

                                         <!--/span-->
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-horizontal">
                                                <label class="control-label">Marca</label>
                                                <input  type="text" id="Marca" class="form-control form-control-danger" placeholder="Marca movil" name="marca" >
                                                </small> </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!--/span-->


                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form horizontal">
                                                <label class="control-label">Fecha desde:</label>

                                                    <input name= "Fechadesde" type="date" id="Fecha1" class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy">
                                                    </small> </div>


                                        </div>

                                         <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form horizontal">
                                                <label class="control-label">Fecha hasta:</label>

                                                    <input name= "Fechahasta "type="date" id="Fecha2" class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy">
                                                    </small> </div>


                                        </div>
```

este es el codigo en python

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
from flask_admin import Admin
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
import MySQLdb



app = Flask(__name__)
mysql = MySQL()

# MySQL configurations
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = ''
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'movedb'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
mysql.init_app(app)
Bootstrap(app)
conn = mysql.connect()

    @app.route('/consultamovil.html', methods=["GET","POST"])
def consultamovil():
    db = mysql.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="",db="movedb")


    cursor = db.cursor()
    varpatente= request.form["patente"]
    varinterno= request.form["interno"]
    varmarca= request.form["marca"]
    vararea= request.form["area"]

    query = "SELECT  moviles.Marca,  moviles.Interno, areas.Area_Responsable FROM moviles, areas where moviles.Id_Area=areas.Id_Area and moviles.Patente= '%s' " % varpatente
    cursor.execute(query)
    var = cursor.fetchone()
    if var != None:
        for (Marca, Interno, Area_Responsable) in cursor:
             varmarca= Marca
             varinterno = Interno
             vararea= Area_Responsable
             return render_template('consultamovil.html', marca=varmarca, interno=varinterno, area=vararea)
```

gracias

Comment: ¿Qué error te aparece?

Comment: Metodo no permitido a veces , no entiendo que estoy haciendo mal ...soy nuevo en esto

Comment: Cuando presiono enter la barra de busqueda del browser me trae consultamovil.html?patente=nph+193&area=&interno=&marca=&Fechadesde=&Fechahasta+=  "No me trae los valores de la base de datos solo coloca el valor de la patente que en este caso es NPH 193